# Image recognition - performance issue

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've got a performance problem in my matlab script.

What I'm trying to do is to find a horizontal line for which variance of intensity values along it is the smallest. The naive implementation is below. The question is how to rewrite it to boost performance.

```
% img is some previously loaded image
height = size(img,1);
width = size(img,2);

smallestVar = inf;
smallestXline = [];
smallestYline = [];

for i=1:height,
    for j=1:width,
        for k=i+1:height,
            xline = [j j];
            yline = [i k];
            variance = var(improfile(img,xline,yline));
            if variance < smallestVar
               smallestVar = variance;
               smallestXline = xline;
               smallestYline = yline;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You could definitely vectorize a lot of this code.  I would start by profiling it first: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html.  The built-in MATLAB profiler is quite nice and will help you get started.  However MATLAB code should always be vectorized when possible.  See Maurits post.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a horizontal line, i.e. all rows of a matrix, you can do it with:

```
sigma = var(matrix, 0, 2);
[val, idx] = sort(sigma, 'ascend');
```

Where `val(1)` will contain the minimum variance and `idx(1)` the corresponding row index. If you are looking for any straight line to scan along, have a look at the so called Trace Transform.

Answer (score 1):

This is a faster way of doing it (based on your description of the problem). Variable row will have the row number which has the minimum variance:

```
[~, row] = min(var(img, 0, 2));
```